# Slicing Strings Using Variables In Batch

Tags: string, batch-file, variables, slice

So I want a program like this:

```
Enter number: 
5
Giving first 5 characters of string "apple pie"...
apple
```

I have tried something like this

```
set characters=5
set "string=apple pie"

set string=%string:~0, %characters%%
```

But it's not working, any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either rewrite

```
set string=%string:~0, %characters%%
```

as

```
call set "string=%%string:~0, %characters%%%"
```

or use delayed expansion

```
@echo off
set characters=5
set "string=apple pie"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=!string:~0, %characters%!"
echo %string%
```

see [Variables in batch not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well, I did try use delayed expansion but I couldn't figure out the exclamation marks.

Comment: IMHO the referred link does not talk about the use of `!this:~0,%combination%!`, but just about Delayed Expansion. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) instead that describe precisely this management, although the topic is different (arrays).